# Права доступа между контейнером и host машиной

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть расшаренная папка между докером и хост машиной. На некоторые файлы докер-рут ставит себя в качестве владельца. Из-за этого нельзя их редактировать с хост машины. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел, нужно было заполнить опцию user в docker-compose.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727548/how-to-configure-docker-compose-yml-to-up-a-container-as-root

https://medium.com/faun/set-current-host-user-for-docker-container-4e521cef9ffc